# Django ModelForm not validating correctly with custom date format

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making a form using Django's forms.ModelForm, but I don't want to use the
default format for the datefield (in my locale, that's `'%Y-%m-%d'`). I don't
remember *why* I wanted to change it, but at this point I'm determined to figure
out what the problem is anyway.
It seems like this question's been asked many times, but most of them are
slightly different, or the answers don't help me.

This is my form class:

```
class RejectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rejection
        fields = ['date',
                  'plant',
                  'part',
                  'defects',
                  'shift',
                  'station',
                  'worker',
                  'quantity',
                  'location',
                  'rejected_by',
                  'remark']
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'date'}, format='%m-%d-%Y')
        }

    error_css_class = 'danger'
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
class RejectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%m,-%d-%Y'],
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            attrs={'class': 'date'},
            format='%m-%d-%Y'
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Rejection
        fields = ['date',
                  'plant',
                  'part',
                  'defects',
                  'shift',
                  'station',
                  'worker',
                  'quantity',
                  'location',
                  'rejected_by',
                  'remark']

    error_css_class = 'danger'
```

But that didn't work, either. Maybe for an entirely different reason, but I got
rid of it. From now on I'll still be referring to the first example.

I've checked the POST data being sent when I submit the form, using Chrome's
developer console, and it's sending it using the format that I want. And when
pre-populated, the value already there is correct, too. So I don't think the
problem is related to the client, or the way the form is rendered.
Something that seems kind of weird is that it *does* validate if I type the date
in the default format. But it still renders it in the custom format.

Furthermore, I've tried it with both L10N and I18N disabled. I got the idea from
the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410058/)
question. Unfortunately (but also kind of fortunately), it didn't work.

Just in case anyone needs it, here's one of the templates:

```
{% extends 'defective/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'defective:edit-id' rej_id=rej_id %}" method="POST" id="rejection_form" class="form-group create-form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table class="table table-hover">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save and view" class="btn btn-primary"><br>
</form>

<script>
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

And the relevant parts of the corresponding view:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Rejection, pk=rej_id)
form = RejectionForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('defective:view-id', kwargs={'rej_id': rej_id}))
else:
    context = {'title': 'Edit an entry',
               'rej_id': rej_id,
               'form': form}
    return render(request, 'defective/edit.html', context)
```

I'm not sure exactly what might be needed, so feel free to ask if you want to see anything else.

Edit: It's probably worth noting that it did work in the past. I'm not certain when it stopped, but I remember it working before I started playing around with [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter).
I decided against using it, and removed everything I added for it. There's nothing I can find that got left, and it didn't even call for editing the views or forms, just adding a new file for filters, and added a URL that pointed to a class-based view that came with the app. Neither of which are present now.

Comment: You second attempt looks correct except that you have a comma in the format (`%m,-%d-%Y`). It should work if you remove the comma.

Comment: That works, thanks. If it comes down to it I'll just do it the manual way, but I'd still like to know _why_ the first one doesn't work.

Comment: Have added an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021652/django-modelform-not-validating-correctly-with-custom-date-format?noredirect=1#comment53899281_33021652), the reason your first approach doesn't work is that the `format` argument on the `DateInput` only controls *the format in which this field’s initial value will be displayed*. (from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format)).

It doesn't control how submitted data is parsed - i.e., the `DateField` will still try to parse submitted data using its default formats. To change that you need the `input_formats` argument on the `DateField` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats)).

So really, you need to set both, as you did in your second attempt. The only problem there was a stray comma in your format.

If you are using consistent date formatting across your entire project, then you can just use the [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS) setting which will correctly configure both the `DateField` and the `DateInput` to use the same format. That way you don't have to specify it individually.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I just thought Django would assume that the format sent in a response is the same one it'd get back. Maybe I had something added that was making it work, before, and just forgot about it. Anyway,thanks!