# DateField in django forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a DateField input in my django form. As far as I can tell, I have been following the documentation well, but it fails validation every time.

Here's the form class-

```
class dForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(input_formats = ["%d/%m/%Y",])
```

This is the views file-

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = dForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', { 'form' : form })
    else:
        data = dForm(request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('ok')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('not ok')
```

And this is the template-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(This is just a trial project, there aren't any other views or forms in it.)

I found this answer with the same issue-

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410058/django-forms-datefield-fails-validation
```

but the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but maybe you should change `data = dForm(request.GET)` to `data = dForm(request.POST)`

Comment: Yup, my bad. But the form still fails validation

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out, in the format string I had put %Y which requires a four digit input for year, but I had been entering a two-digit year all along.